# nested initializer list ambiguity for list of lists each containing a single item

Tags: c++, nested, implicit-conversion, initializer-list

I'm writing a Permutation class which I'd like to initialize using an initializer_list (one-form notation) or a nested initializer_list (cycle notation). I came across a overload disambiguation error for which I've prepared the following minimal example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <initializer_list>
class SomeClass{
public:
  SomeClass(std::initializer_list<int> init)
  {
    std::cout << "Constructor 1" << std::endl;
  }

  SomeClass(std::initializer_list<std::initializer_list<int>> init)
  {
    std::cout << "Constructor 2" << std::endl;
  }
};

int main()
{
  SomeClass({{1},{2}});
  return 0;
}
```

which yields the following compiler error (edited for clarity):

```
nested_init.cpp: In function ‘int main()’: nested_init.cpp:23:22: 
error: call of overloaded ‘SomeClass(<brace-enclosed initializer list>)’ 
is ambiguous SomeClass({{1},{2}});
nested_init.cpp:14:3: note: candidate:
SomeClass::SomeClass(std::initializer_list<std::initializer_list<int>>)
SomeClass(std::initializer_list<std::initializer_list<int>> init)     
nested_init.cpp:9:3: note: candidate:
SomeClass::SomeClass(std::initializer_list<int>)   
SomeClass(std::initializer_list<int> init)
nested_init.cpp:3:7: note: candidate: 
constexpr SomeClass::SomeClass(const SomeClass&)
nested_init.cpp:3:7: note: candidate:
constexpr SomeClass::SomeClass(SomeClass&&)
```

After playing around with it, I think I've figured out why this happens. The {1} and {2} can implicitly be converted to 1 and 2 respectively. The compiler gets confused as to which constructor to use then.
I can make do, and ignore those cases since in my particular use case the cycle notation is the identity if every list inside the list of lists is composed of of single element. However I'd like to know how to prevent this implicit conversation happening in the future. How would this be accomplished?

Comment: Try making the constructor `explicit`?

Comment: It doesn't change anything. The problem isn't that some function is using these constructors to implicitly convert its inputs. The problem is that {1} gets implicitly converted to 1. I'd have to declate the int "constructor" to be explicit, which even if possible would be liable to cause unexpected problems elsewhere. What I need is something that can say: don't implicitly convert the arguments of this function.

Answer (score 1):

As you say, `{1}` and `{2}` in your example can be converted to `int 1` and `int 2` with *direct-list-initialization* and thus there occurs ambiguity.
For instance, 8.5.4 in n3337 (a draft of C++ standard) states

> ```
> Otherwise, if the initializer list has a single element, the object or reference 
> is initialized from that element; ...
> [ Example:
>    int x1 {2}; // OK
>    int x2 {2.0}; // error: narrowing 
> — end example ]
> ```

One simple way to avoid this ambiguity is using double braces `{{...}}` and explicitly creating a `std::initializer_list`.
For instance, following code calls the second constructor of `SomeClass` with a nested initializer list `{ { int{1} }, { int{2} }}`:

```
SomeClass({ {{1}}, {{2}} });
```

OTOH, following code calls the second constructor with a nested initializer list `{ { int{1}, int{2} } }`:

```
SomeClass({ { {1}, {2} } });
```

Direct-list-initialization and copy-list-initialization are also works in this way:

[**DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/87e06791b8e4772a)

```
// direct-list-initialization
SomeClass a{ {{1}}, {{2}} }; // Constructor 2 with a nested initializer_list { { int{1} }, { int{2} }}
SomeClass b{ { {1}, {2} } }; // Constructor 2 with a nested initializer_list { { int{1}, int{2} } }

// copy-list-initialization
SomeClass d = { {{1}}, {{2}} }; // Constructor 2 with a nested initializer_list { { int{1} }, { int{2} }}
SomeClass e = { { {1}, {2} } }; // Constructor 2 with a nested initializer_list { { int{1}, int{2} } }
```

Answer (score 0):

Single element `{1}` is automatically converted  to `1`. Compiler does not know which version of constuctor uses because both are correct. I think so it can be a problem. In c++11 you can use such initiations: `int a {1};`